# How do i checked another checkbox when i checked a checkbox(same class) and insert value into a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a checkbox with same class, basically what it does is that if i checked the checkbox it will checked the same class as the checkbox and it will return value. But it will not return directly, i need to click somewhere then it register to the textbox. What i need is straight-forward value into the textbox when i checked the checkbox. The table code is from php so the class+number will change and its not fix.

Below is the snippet for it.

```js
function doSomethingElse(row) {
  //select all checkboxes with name userid that are checked
  var checkboxes =
    document.querySelectorAll("input[name='student_name[]']:checked")

  var values = "";

  //append values of each checkbox into a variable (seperated by commas)
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    values += checkboxes[i]
      .value + ","
  }

  //remove last comma
  values = values.slice(0, values.length - 1)

  //set the value of input box
  document.getElementById("stud_name").value = values;

}


$("input:checkbox").change(function() {
  //alert('Ok!');
  var value = $(this).attr("class");
  $(":checkbox[class='" + value + "']").prop("checked", this.checked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr onclick="doSomethingElse(this);">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="something1" name="user_id[]" value='' /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="something1" name="student_name[]" value='1' /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="something2" name="student_name[]" value='' /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="something2" name="user_id[]" value='2' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input class="form-control" name="stud_name" id="stud_name" type="text" maxlength="255" />
```

Comment: The second `script` tag in your HTML is broken

Comment: it is broken but it works, i can click on the first checkbox and it does checked the checkbox wit hthe same class

Comment: It broke the snippet, but as it was a duplication of the previous jQuery reference, I presumed it was just a typo, so I removed it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$("input:checkbox").click(function () {` instead of `change`

```js
function doSomethingElse(row){

  //select all checkboxes with name userid that are checked
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='student_name[]']:checked")

  var values = "";

  //append values of each checkbox into a variable (seperated by commas)
  for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
    values += checkboxes[i].value + ","
  }

  //remove last comma
  values = values.slice(0,values.length-1);

  //set the value of input box
  document.getElementById("stud_name").value = values;

}

$("input:checkbox").click(function () {
  //alert('Ok!');
  var value = $(this).attr("class");
  $(":checkbox[class='" + value + "']").prop("checked", this.checked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
 <tr onclick="doSomethingElse(this);">

    <td><input type="checkbox" class ="something1"name="user_id[]" value='ID1' /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class ="something1"name="student_name[]" value='NAME1' /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class ="something2"name="student_name[]" value='NAME2' /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class ="something2"name="user_id[]" value='ID2' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input class="form-control" name="stud_name" id="stud_name" type="text" maxlength="255" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to figure out exactly what you want from your question, but I've given it a try.

Firstly, is there an error in your HTML? Should the below:

```
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="something2" name="student_name[]" value='' /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="something2" name="user_id[]" value='2' /></td>
```

actually be:

```
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="something2" name="student_name[]" value='2' /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="something2" name="user_id[]" value='' /></td>
```

Notice the values swapped around.

I think to solve your problem you can do all the work in the onchange like below:

```js
$("input:checkbox").change(function () {
  //alert('Ok!');
  var value = $(this).attr("class");
  $(":checkbox[class='" + value + "']").prop("checked", this.checked);
  
  var checkboxes = $("input[name='student_name[]']:checked");
  var values = "";

  //append values of each checkbox into a variable (seperated by commas)
  for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++) {
    values += checkboxes[i].value + ","
  }

  //remove last comma
  values = values.slice(0,values.length-1)

  //set the value of input box
  $("#stud_name").val(values);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>

      <td><input type="checkbox" class ="something1"name="user_id[]" value='' /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class ="something1"name="student_name[]" value='1' /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class ="something2"name="student_name[]" value='2' /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class ="something2"name="user_id[]" value='' /></td>
    </tr>
 </table>

 <input class="form-control" name="stud_name" id="stud_name" type="text" maxlength="255" />
```

I've also tried to improve your formatting a bit and stuck to using only jquery selectors

Comment: Hey thansk for helping me out, but it didnt return the value of the checkbox to the textbox,anyway it is solved. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, sorry. Made a mistake when swapping document.getElementById for a jquery selector. It's fixed now

Answer (score 1):

I've got you a working fiddle over her; https://jsfiddle.net/nd01p86t/15/

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="something1" name="user_id[]" value='' /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="something1" name="student_name[]" value='1' /> </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="something2" name="student_name[]" value='' /> </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="something2" name="user_id[]" value='2' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input class="form-control" name="stud_name" id="stud_name" type="text" maxlength="255" />
```

THE functions...

```
function doSomethingElse(row) {
  //select all checkboxes with name userid that are checked
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[name$='[]']:checked")
  // OR...
  //var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked")

  //append values of each checkbox into a variable (seperated by commas)

  var values = Array.from(checkboxes).filter( checkbox => checkbox.value ).map( checkbox => checkbox.value ).join(',');

  //set the value of input box
  document.getElementById("stud_name").value = values;
}

//  Attach to the table and delegate 'click' per row
$("table").delegate("tr", "click", doSomethingElse);


$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
  //alert('Ok!');
  var value = $(this).attr("class");
  $(":checkbox[class='" + value + "']").prop("checked", this.checked);
})
```